# How to set different bootstrap class depends on condition in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

How do I use `Vue` to set the bootstrap class name? If `isIndividual`, it is using `.col-md-12` else it will be `.col-md-6`

I tried with this but it doesn't work if `isIndividual` is true.

```
  .row
    .col-md-12(v-if="isIndividual")
    .col-md-6(v-if="!isIndividual")
    .col-md-6(v-if="!isIndividual")
```

Basically, if `isIndividual` is true, then it is just one column. Else, it will be two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div :class="isIndividual ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-6' ">
  </div>
</div>
```